# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ConnectedServices, how to install?

Tags: visual-studio, error-handling, nuget-package

Apologies if this is not the right place to ask a question like this.
Also sorry for bad english ;)

I have Visual Studio 2015 (Version 14.0 I think) on Windows 7.
My skills: Hello World level, I just started.

> Error: I can't close Visual Studio, without killing it in the task manager. When I try, this pops up:
>   [image]

After some google search, I read about installing some package
(can't provide links, am new here)

> I tried doing so in the package manager console and I get this error:
>   [image]

How do I fix this? How can I install this package/ will this fix the error?

I'm at the very beginning and I don't really have a clue what's going on, it's frustrating to deal with such errors while learning the basics of programming. Please help me out!
Thank you very much

Answer (score 4):

You need to copy the Visual Studio Connected Services assembly so that devenv.exe can load it. More details here http://vijayshinva.github.io/visual%20studio/.net/2016/03/31/visual-studio-2015-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-visualstudio-connectedservices.html

Comment: Pukka. You have save my times. Great.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, I need "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\qmj5qqhp.mic\Microsoft.VisualStudio.ConnectedServices.Package2.dll" and can't figure out how to get that.

Answer (score 2):

This error is due to unavailability of **Visual Studio Connected Services SDK 2.0.0** package

I think you have already got the answer with you you. 
But the reason for it is not working is,

> You haven't specified any **Package Source** in the package manager Console.

You can select **nuget.org** from the dropdown list as shown in the picture & run the code again

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.ConnectedServices
```

[image]

**Note** : make sure you are connected to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

In my case "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\ConnectedServices\Microsoft.VisualStudio.ConnectedServices.Package2.dll" was 0 kilobyte. You can't get the package2 file from NuGet. I was able to restore the file from a backup. After restoring the file, Visual Studio is working fine again.